# Is there any extension in Emacs for fuzzy completion as you type similar to Sublime

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, fuzzy

I tried **auto-complete-mode**. but suggestions are **not fuzzy**, it needs exact match.

Also tried (global-set-key (kbd "M-C-I") '**ac-fuzzy-complete**), but this needs trigger (not as you type).

Below is a screenshot for **Sublime**. Even *'hw'* suggests *helloWorld*

[image]

Something similar in Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lewang/flx

Here is the package for Emacs. It's been super stable and you can setup with helm, ivy, or auto complete packages

Comment: I need to get suggestions 'as you type' in the main buffer. I could see this useful in the mini buffer suggestion. Is there any working config for auto-complete-mode with this.

Comment: This issue https://github.com/lewang/flx/issues/43 may have ideas: a snippet and a link to ido-at-point (but both need a key trigger).

Comment: @champions Company is another popular auto-complete front end for Emacs and Flx do support it https://github.com/PythonNut/company-flx